# How to import SFTP (File.tar.gz) to Nifi

Tags: csv, gzip, apache-nifi, tar

I have a tar.gz file which contains a set of CSV files in it. How do I read only one file into nifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetFile` -> `compressContent` with decompress mode gzip -> `unpackContent` with tar format -> `routeOnAttribut` with `${fileName}`.